# Rambam midrash book

Tags: rambam

I always hear Rav Breitowitz say in his shiurim that the Rambam told us he was gonna write a book about midrashim and their rational explanations, but that he never got around to doing so. Anyone know where the rambam told us this?

Comment: He said that he would in his commentary to Mishnah and that he changed his mind in Moreh Nevuchim. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120661/6592) and [here](https://www.orharambam.com/post/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9D) for details.

Comment: Thanks @shmosel

Comment: @shmosel you should write that as an answer.

Comment: I was going to but I changed my mind.